# What brand of faucet is this and how can I hook the sink sprayer up to it?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, kitchens

The sprayer for my faucet is not hooked up to anything, the rubber hose just dangles below the sink. I'd really like to get this wired up, as it would be very handy to have, but I have no idea how to go about doing this.  I have two primary issues

1) What brand of faucet is this?

[image: Picture of faucet]

2) How do I hook up the sprayer to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Price Pfister T26-4NRR Marielle Hole Kitchen Single Handle Faucet

Comment: And with that, we can then find the [installation manual](http://www.pfisterfaucets.com/www/ImageAssets/mirror/model/kitchen/marielle/mart26-4n/26548-0500.pdf) (see step #14)

Answer (score -1):

about 2)

If by sprayer you mean the leftmost unit, in the units I've seen, you dont hook it up to the faucet per se, the sprayer is a separate faucet that is hooked up to the water supply separately. You will have to set up a T or Y junction to attach the sprayer unit.

Comment: Wrong!!!  It attaches to the faucet stem on a second connection. When the sprayer is used, it stops the flow from the faucet.  Lool for a second 3/8 inch male connector, which now must have an end seal cap.  If it doesn't, then it wasn't designed for a sprayer. I can't believe a high end set like that doesn't have the bypass connector coming out of the bottom of the lever pack or the stem head.  A "T" or "Y" valve would only give you half pressure.  Not the way it is done. The only other thing I can imagine is that the piece next to the sprayer is a valve. It looks like a soap dispenser.

Comment: @shirlock it's a soap dispenser and there isn't an obvious connector hanging capped. I'll try and get a picture of the underside.